# How to evaluate methods timing in Visual Studio

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

I developed a very complex webservice that performs a lot of operation, in particular operation on SqlServer.

Is it possible, while I'm attached to the deployed webservice, to monitor timing of every methods to understand where are the most time consuming ones?

Otherwise I've to put in my code a lot of stopwatches, and write somewhere the result.

Any idea to achieve my goal within visual studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Logging with stopwatches is good idea especially for undefined-time operations like calling a web service. This will enable you to investigate issues in release environment.

But if you have to investigate some performance issue locally, nothing is better than a specialized performance **profiler**. Visual studio 2010 (and I believe 2013) has a very good performance analyzer (included in Developer, Team and Ultimate editions as I remember). [Here is beginner guide on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx).

There are plenty other profilers, but for the needs you've described integrated Visual studio profiler will be more than fine.

Comment: Great! I knew that exists profiler, but can I use on an already deployed webservice? I mean: profiler usually "start" the project and profiles it. I have an already deployed webservice and I want to profile that. Does profile fit to my scenario?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, though a bit harder. You need all *.pdb files of the deployed version and attach profiler to existing process. Here is link how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182384.aspx. Other option is when you don't need to profile service internals and only know total time of every service method call, you can attach profiler to local service client application and call service few times from it.

Comment: I have to use the first option because (as far as I understand) with the second option I can profile the webservice methods (the endpoints), but I want to profile also the private methods inside webservice . fortunately there is no problem to copy pdbs! :)

Comment: Unfortunately the guide you suggested me allow you only to attach to local processes..any suggestion to attch remotely as in my case?